# How to add option of "save image to gallery" in share via menu in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, share, save-image

I am sharing an image to different apps using an intent as ACTION_SEND, but I also want to add an option of "Save image to gallery", in the same menu.

Is there any way to do it ? Please help me somebody.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to create custom dialog for that.
add all ACTION_SEND items to your list and "save image to gallery" option also.
put this listview in some dialog.

refer this :

https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

use this code to get available items of ACTION_SEND

```
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    List<ResolveInfo> listGel = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listGel) {
        Log.e("package",res.activityInfo.packageName);
        Log.e("name",res.activityInfo.name);
        Log.e("proname",res.loadLabel(context.getPackageManager()).toString());


    }
```

Comment: thanks Ravi, for such an immediate reply. 
I have started the activity but there is no image to share with the selected app.
please if you help me for this also...

Comment: Have any alternative with this library?